# Golang how can I multiply a integer and a float

Tags: go

I am trying to resize the dimensions of an image but am getting a **constant 0.8 truncated to integer** error on compile . This is my code

```
b := img.Bounds()

heightImg := b.Max.Y  // height of image in pixels
widthImg := b.Max.X   // width of image in pixels
const a = .80
height := int(heightImg * a) // reduce height by 20%
width := int(widthImg * a)  // reduce width by 20%

 // resize image below which take in type int, int in the 2nd & 3rd parameter
new_img := imaging.Resize(img,width,height, imaging.Lanczos)
```

I am new to golang but this code right here gives me the error

```
    height := int(heightImg * a) 
    width := int(widthImg * a)
```

any suggestions would be great

Comment: You may find it useful to read up on how `constants` are expressed in go. Specifically in this case, because your original code multiplies `a` with an integer, the constant is converted to and `int` as well for compatability. https://blog.golang.org/constants

Comment: Thanks for the link will read that now

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you want to multiply floats, you need to convert the number to a float:

```
height := int(float64(heightImg) * a) 
width := int(float64(widthImg) * a)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var xx float64
xx = 0.29
fmt.Println(xx, xx * 100)
```

The result is 28.999999999999996, convert to int is 28

```
var xx float32
xx = 0.29
fmt.Println(xx * 100)
```

The result is 29, convert to int is 29